# send udp packets to a destination via forwarding

Tags: linux, ip, forwarding

i have linux machine A ( 128.247.19.194, netmask 255.255.254.0)
linux machine B ( 128.247.19.165 netmask 255.255.254.0)
And another linux machine (128.247.19.3 netmask 255.255.254.0)

There is a security tunnel between A and B. 
I want to send packets from C to A via B.How can i do that?

I have set the ip_forward bit in the linux machine B.

What i am trying to test and learn is the generation of inner ipv4 fragments when i send say a 2000 byte packet from C to B - it gets fragmented and then these fragments gets encapsulated in outer ip and go to A.

But i have not been able to achieve this, the wireshark says destination unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a route on machine C:

route add -host 128.247.19.194 gateway 128.247.19.165

You may also need a route on machine A, something like this:

route add -host 128.247.19.3 gateway 128.247.19.164

But first, try only with the route on machine C, if it does not work, add also the route for the A machine.